# Why are there different Versions of Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack in NuGet and what is the right one

Tags: nuget, windows-api-code-pack

In one of my older projects, I use the Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack-Shell (and -Core) package (1.1.0.2) from Microsoft. I wanted to include these packages in one of my current project, only to find a lot of veeery similar looking packages (Microsoft-WindowsAPICodePack-Shell, Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.Shell, ...) but all of them not from Microsoft.

[image: NuGet plugin in Visual Studio 2019]

My first thought was this might be some kind of fraud, but they have millions of downloads and I do not find the package from Microsoft in NuGet. From what I understand is, that there were no updates from MS anymore, so people started to fork it

Is this how it is supposed to be and if yes, which of the "copycat" package should I use?

Thanks in advance,
Frank

I searched the MS Projects in NuGet and tried to find something about these other projects. They seem to be legit, but I wonder why there are more than one and which one to use ...

Comment: As far as I can tell, the library basically just provided Windows APIs to managed code. Is that right? If so, the Windows team have an officially supported alternative now: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/desktop/modernize/desktop-to-uwp-enhance

Comment: Just to note that as a C# outsider, this post and especially screenshot was very useful for me, to motivate me to find that WindowsAPICodePack is actually in Tools/NuGet Package Manager/Manage NuGet Packages for Solution in Visual Studio 2019 Community